# How do you round a number to correct uncertainty?

Tags: python, significant-digits, uncertainty

In python, I have a number: `U = 0.02462631224438585 +- 3.350971888120506e-06`.

How do I round it to the correct significant figures due to the uncertainty being rounded to `1s.f.`?
Is there an easy way of using `numpy`? Or `scipy` or are the built-in function the best for this?

I've tried using `set_printoptions(precision=3)` but this doesn't work.
I've also tried using `round(number, significant - len(str(number)))`, but this seems long-winded.

I'm sure I have used a function that is simply a couple of years ago without having to create my own.

The final number should be `U = 2.4626e-02 +- 3e-06`

or `U = (2.4626 +- 3e-4)e-02`

Comment: Do you mean you want it *printed* in that way, while retaining the value originally stored in data, or do you actually want to truncate the variable?

Comment: On my phone so I can't give a full answer but you should look at the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) package. It supports exact floating point arithmetic and rounding for precision.

Comment: I'm putting it into a dictionary but I'm being assessed on the uncertainty so it has to be the actual variable that changes

Answer (score 4):

the [`uncertainties`](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) module has the capability of computing the number of significant digits

```
import uncertainties
a = uncertainties.ufloat(0.02462631224438585, 3.350971888120506e-06)
print(a)
# 0.0246263+/-0.0000034
```

the defaut is two significant digits, however there is a `format` key for controlling the output

```
print('{:.1u}, {:.3uf}, {:.2uL}, {:0.2ue}'.format(a,a,a,a))
# 0.024626+/-0.000003, 0.02462631+/-0.00000335, 0.0246263 \pm 0.0000034, (2.46263+/-0.00034)e-02
```